# the l-value must be modifiable error

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

this is a function to fix the red black tree,but compiler keeps giving the l-value must be modifiable,the 'z' in the while loop condition is causing problem (z != root), the while should r.un until the z pointer which is point a particular key reaches the key the 'z' pointer is pointing to

```
void Tree::fixup(int z)
{
fixuppri(root, z);
}

 void Tree::fixuppri(node* root, int a)
{
node* z ;
z = returnnode(a);

while (z != root && z->parent->color = 'r')
{
    node* y;

    if (z->parent == z->parent->parent->left)
    {
        y = z->parent->parent->right;
    }
    else
    {
        y = z->parent->parent->left;
    }

    if (y->color = 'r')
    {
        z->parent->parent->color = 'r';
        z->parent->color = 'b';
        y->color = 'b';
        z = z->parent->parent;
    }
    else
    {
        if (z->parent == z->parent->parent->left && z == z->parent->left)
        {
            char tempcolor = z->parent->color;
            z->parent->color = z->parent->parent->color;
            z->parent->parent->color = tempcolor;
            rightrotate(z->parent->parent);
        }
        if (z->parent == z->parent->parent->left && z == z->parent->right)
        {
            char tempcolor = z->color;
            z->color = z->parent->parent->color;
            z->parent->parent->color = tempcolor;
            leftrotate(z->parent);
            rightrotate(z->parent->parent);
        }
        if (z->parent == z->parent->parent->right && z == z->parent->right)
        {
            char tempcolor = z->parent->color;
            z->parent->color = z->parent->parent->color;
            z->parent->parent->color = tempcolor;
            leftrotate(z->parent->parent);
        }
        if (z->parent == z->parent->parent->right && z == z->parent->left)
        {
            char tempcolor = z->color;
            z->color = z->parent->parent->color;
            z->parent->parent->color = tempcolor;
            rightrotate(z->parent);
            leftrotate(z->parent->parent);
        }
    }


}

root->color = 'b';
 }
```

Comment: `z->parent->color = 'r'` did you mean `==`? There's another further down too. Maybe you should have a look at basic syntax before RB trees.

Comment: oh man, that was the problem

Comment: yup it went away, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple typo causing a confusing error because of interaction with operator precedence.

You wrote `=` where you should have written `==`.

`&&` has lower precedence than `==`, but higher precedence than `=`.

This means that

```
z != root && z->parent->color = 'r'
```

is equivalent to

```
(z != root && z->parent->color) = 'r'
```

and `z != root && z->parent->color` is not a modifiable l-value.